# Does VC++ compile down to Intel machine code or intermediate code?

Tags: function, visual-c++, pointers, assembly, x86-16

I am wondering if the function pointers in VC++ can be pointed to a preinitialised memory block containing x86 machine code. Could I then execute the code at that location using a function pointer ?

ie

```
void (*functionPointerToStartOfCodeSegment)(void);

functionPointerToStartOfCodeSegment = 0x4A152;

*functionPointerToStartOfCodeSegment();
```

Will this continue to execute the x86 code at location 0x4A152 or will it choke because it is expecting intermediate code at that location ?

Comment: The title and the question body don't really match, what exactly are you asking?

Answer (score 3):

Your top level question:
"Does VC++ compile down to machine code or intermediate code?"
You'd have to ask MS.

But given they are targeting different platforms (at least CLR and native x86), I'd guess the compiler operates in stages:

- Parse VC++
- Generate a high-level "intermediate" representation of the C++ code
- a) Generate CLR code or b) generate native x86 code

I'm not sure what the connection between your main question and the detailed question is, but anyway...

Yes, you should be able to set a VC++ function pointer to point to an arbitrary block of x86 code using a cast.  You have to make sure that code follows all the VC++ calling/returning conventions.   If the VC++ code is compiled as CLR code, the calling conventions likely include ways to signal that the function is either more CLR code, or native x86 code.  Check the MS documentation for calling conventions.

Comment: I see the confusion. What I want to do is write C++ code and compile it in VC++, one core component. I then want other people to write libraries and access them from the main component. I am hoping that the function pointer won't see garbage. Is that clearer ?

Comment: Function pointers work in C++ without trouble. Your situation sounds like C++ "main component" calling C++ "libraries you code" through function pointers. Why isn't this just standard function calling via function pointers?